# jQuery draggable seems not to be working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a html structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js "></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="skrypt.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body  style="background-color:#FF8787">
        <div class="box">
            <br/>
            <div id="container"> 
                <div class="droppable object"></div>
                <div class="droppable object"></div>
                <div class="droppable object"></div>
                <div class="droppable object"></div>
                <div class="droppable object"></div>
                <div class="droppable object"></div>
                <div class="droppable object"></div>
                <div class="droppable object"></div>
                <div class="droppable object"></div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div id="draggable-container">
                <div class="draggable" style="background-color: blue"></div>
                <div class="draggable" style="background-color: red"></div>
                <div class="draggable" style="background-color: green"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

with css file (stylesheet.css):

```
#container {
    height: 300px;
    width:300px;
    background-color: #08457e;
    margin: auto;
}
.object {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #00AFB8;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 18.5px 18.5px 18.5px 18.5px;
}

.draggable {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}

.task {
    height: 30px;
}
```

Using jQuery draggable, droppable and resizable widgets, I want to make the ".draggable" divs to be used more than once. It seems that after the first use (dragging), they lose their ui-draggable class and I believe this is the problem. The same goes with newly created objects. If I properly dropped a  draggable div, the newly created ".task" div can be resized but not dragged.
Here is jQuery code for that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        snapMode: 'inner',
        helper: myHelper
    });
    $('.droppable').droppable({
        accept: '.draggable, .task',
        drop: ondrop
    });
});

function myHelper(event, ui){
    return $(this).clone();
}

function ondrop(event,ui){
    var object = ui.draggable.clone().removeClass('draggable').addClass('task');
    makeDraggable(object);
    makeResizable(object);
    $(this).append(object);
}

function makeResizable(element){
    $(element).resizable();
}

function makeDraggable(element){
    $(element).draggable({
        helper: function(){ 
          return $(this).clone();
        },        
        zIndex: 10
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite see why your code isn't working but you shouldn't need to clone in the helper handler and again in the drop handler, where `ui.helper` gives you access to the (already cloned) helper.

Also, `.clone(true)` will include all the original element's data and events, thereby you *should* avoid the need to re-invoke `.draggable()` on the dropped clone.

You might end up with something like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        'snapMode': 'inner',
        'helper': function(event, ui) {
            return $(this).clone(true).get(0); // the documentation says to return an element, not jQuery object.
        }
        'zIndex': 10 // 'zIndex' is a draggable option that affects the dragged element while it is being dragged.
    });
    $('.droppable').droppable({
        'accept': '.draggable, .task',
        'drop': function(event, ui) {
            ui.helper.removeClass('draggable').addClass('task').resizable().appendTo(this); // add .css('zIndex', 10) to control the zIndex of the cloned/appended element, if that's what you want.
        }
    });
});
```

Somewhere in all that, you *may* get the desired effect - no promises.